# C# wcf protobuf client

Tags: c#, wcf, protobuf-net

I have a Protobuf WCF Service. Everything works fine when I consume it.
Data is Protobuf and everythings good.

But now I want to use the same class I use with the Protobuf attributes
without Protobuf. How can someone achive that?
I want to consume the service that has Protobuf implemented without protobuf.
And I dont want to change/add another exact class just to have both ways.

EDIT:

```
var customBinding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding();
        customBinding.Elements.Add(new System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion.Soap11, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
        var httpsBindingElmnt = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        httpsBindingElmnt.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        httpsBindingElmnt.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
        //httpsBindingElmnt.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        //httpsBindingElmnt.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
        //httpsBindingElmnt.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
        //httpsBindingElmnt.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
        //httpsBindingElmnt.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
        //httpsBindingElmnt.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
        //httpsBindingElmnt.Name = "VaultBasicHttpBinding";

        httpsBindingElmnt.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
        httpsBindingElmnt.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
        //httpsBindingElmnt.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
        customBinding.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElmnt);

        //string address = "https://adress/MobileService.svc";
        //Uri baseAddress = new Uri(address);
        //ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(MobileService.MobileServiceClient), baseAddress);
        //ChannelFactory<MobileService.MobileServiceClient> factory = new ChannelFactory<MobileService.MobileServiceClient>(customBinding, address);
        //MobileService.MobileServiceClient client = factory.CreateChannel();


        MobileService.MobileServiceClient client = new MobileService.MobileServiceClient(customBinding,
            new EndpointAddress("https://adress/MobileService.svc"));
        //MobileService.MobileServiceClient client = new MobileService.MobileServiceClient(customBinding,
        //   new EndpointAddress("http://127.0.0.1:4501/MobileService.svc"));

        client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoEndpointBehavior());
```

And after that iam using the client objects functions.

Comment: Tell us what you mean by `consume`.

Comment: @mjwills by consume iam meaning open a channelfactory in another application (client) and use the services interface functions